# Nginx map directive only uses one condition

Tags: nginx

In Nginx I have two map blocks that neither works properly.

1- I want to use dynamic ssl certificate and also one domain has a wildcard certificate. This was what I think would work but it always uses the wildcard condition and never the default:

```
map $host $ssl_server_name {
        *.example.com     'example.com';
        default             $host;
}

//later ($ssl_server_name is always example.com)

ssl_certificate /home/ssl/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /home/ssl/$ssl_server_name/privkey.pem;
```

2- I want to set a header only for the above domain so I used this:

```
map $host $header_value {
       default 'another_value';
       *.example.com 'header_value';
}

// later ($header_value is always 'another_value')
proxy_set_header X-TEST-HEADER $header_value;
```

Comment: 1. will not work because `$host` is unknown when `ssl_certificate` is loaded. 2. will not work because you have forgotten to include the `hostnames` special parameter. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map).

Comment: @RichardSmith could you provide an answer that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Map on ssl_server_name, witch is known. Also add hostnames.

```
map $ssl_server_name $ssl_server_name {
        hostnames;
        *.example.com     'example.com';
        default            $ssl_server_name;
}
    
ssl_certificate /home/ssl/$ssl_server_name/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /home/ssl/$ssl_server_name/privkey.pem;
```